# Resize-Partition errors after first execution in DSC script

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to use the following piece of code in a powershell DSC script.  It runs fine on first execution but on following executions it throws an error as it's already expanded.

Here's the command:

```
       $MaxSize = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter c).sizeMax
       Resize-Partition -DriveLetter c -Size $MaxSize
```

What's the best way to get my script running with no error on subsequent runs?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following parameter to Resize-Partition:

```
-ErrorAction Continue
```

it's a [common parameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6#erroraction) and allows you to choose how Powershell responds to errors with the cmdlet

Comment: Probably should use SILENTLYContinue if the desired state is to not display or log any errors.